# LogParser Query Expecting From Keyword Instead of Token 'To_Timestamp'

Tags: sql, logging, iis, logparser

I am writing a query in LogParser Studio (and have also tried it in command line LogParser 2.2) in trying to find results that have a date between two specified dates in the query.
I get the error message (below) whenever I run it.

```
Error parsing query: Syntax Error: <from-clause>:expecting FROM keyword instead 
of token 'TO_TIMESTAMP(date,time)' [SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.]
```

Here is the query (below).  Note that I do replace '[LOGFILEPATH]' with the actual path when I try this in the command line LogParser.  The path to the log files is `\inetpubs\logs\b\*.log`
Also, I've tried removing the single quotes in the dates, with no positive results.
Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT LocalDateTime,  USING TO_TIMESTAMP(date,time) AS LocalDateTime into 
OUTPUT.CSV FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]' where LocalDateTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP ('2012-01-06 
13:50:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') And TIMESTAMP ('2012-01-07 14:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd 
hh:mm:ss') order by LocalDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Your problem is due to the comma between `LocalDateTime` and `USING`.

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your query to fit my log. My log file doesn't have LocalDateTime so I change it to s-ip. I also removed into OUTPUT.CSV because there's another issue. I'm not sure if you have same issue. But it can work after remove it.

[image]

If you also have this issue, try to remove into OUTPUT.CSV .

So the issue is caused by USING TO_TIMESTAMP(date,time). If you want to use TO_TIMESTAMP function, just use it and no need to add USING.

Same error with you.

[image]

But it worked well after I removed the USING.

[image]